# How can you take public transport from Hamilton Airport to Toronto?

Tags: airport-transfer, ontario

My grandpa lives near Finch TTC station in Toronto and fancies flying [Swoop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swoop_(airline)). He'd be landing on Friday night. But its only destination in Ontario is, and it only flies to, Hamilton (CYHM).

It feels easiest to rent a car at CYHM, drive home to Toronto, and return the car near his home the next day. But [this looks too expensive at $300 CAD (post-tax)](https://www.ca.kayak.com/cars/YHM-a22926/YYZ-a11592/2018-10-17-23h/2018-10-18-18h?sort=rank_a). He knows that it can cost more  to rent at airports, and to return to a different location.

1. Is there convenient public transport between CYHM and Finch TTC?
2. If not, is there a cheaper rental car option?

Comment: The cheapest is _walking_. It's free. Be more specific. Or check rome2rio.com.

Comment: Do shared shuttles/out of town vans satisfy your definition of "public transit"?

Comment: What day of the week?

Comment: @NateEldredge Added.

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk Yes, but I think we have the same one in mind? They're at least $120 post-tax/journey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Transit suggests this will require 3 different systems:

- Hamilton transit #20 from the airport to Go bus stop
- Go bus to Aldershot Go station
- Go train to Union
- TTC to Finch

It will take almost 3 hours. (Driving, when there is no traffic, would take about an hour.) I expect the fare would be in the $20-$30 range total.

(I wanted to share the link to the google transit page, but goo.gl links are forbidden. You can repeat the search if you need specific bus and train numbers.)

Comment: It looks like route 20 only runs weekdays.

Comment: That makes it even more awkward!